# RegEx to update background= URLs

Tags: regex

What I'm trying to do is update the URLs of HTML background tags in a document. The caveat being only local URLs should be updated, so anything starting http should be ignored.

The RegEx I'm trying to achieve needs to replace the path before the filename & extension. so for example:

```
background="image.gif"
background="/image.gif"
background="images/image.gif"
background="images/directory/image.gif"
```

should all output as:

```
background="/mydirectory/image.gif"
```

As always, both single or double quotes may have been used in the input file.

I already have an existing RegEx that is doing a very similar job for the CSS image references. The RegEx is:

```
url\((?:\'|\"")?(?!(?:http|ftp))(?<path>.+)\/(?<filename>.*?)\1?\)
```

I thought I would simply be able to replace the url() match with background= but so far I've not been successful.

Any help greatly apprechiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eC0xZ1/10)
Regex `background=['"](?!\s*(http|ftp):\/\/)(?:[^'"]*\/)*(?<filename>[^'"]+)['"]`

In details:

- `baground=`match 'background=' literraly
- `['"]` match any quote
- `(?!\s*(http|ftp):\/\/)` ensure after the quote there's not http:// or ftp:// (even with spaces before)
- `(?:[^'"]*\/)*` match the path until the filename when still inside the quotes `[^'"]*\/` included in a non capturing group which `(?:)`which can be repeated 0 or more time by `*` (could be replaced by `?` as it will match all or nothing in fact)
- `(?<filename>[^'"]+)` capture anything not a quote (and non empty by `+`quantifier) in the capture group filename
- `['"]` match the last quote to avoid capturing it

Old Answer (in case it interest some):
[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/eC0xZ1/8)

the regex is: `background=['"](?!\s*(http|ftp):\/\/)\/?(?<filename>[^'"]*)['"]`

In details:

- `baground=`match 'background=' literraly
- `['"]` match any quote
- `(?!\s*(http|ftp):\/\/)` ensure after the quote there's not http:// or ftp:// (even with spaces before)
- `\/?` match the leading / to avoid capture it if present
- `(?<filename>[^'"]*)` capture anything not a quote in the capture group filename
- `['"]` match the last quote to avoid capturing it

See the demo for replacing, but the idea is to replace by `/mydir/${filename}`

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai, that's almost perfect! The only issue is I need to remove everything before the filename in the source e.g at the moment an input of '/images/directory/image.gif' is outputting as '/mydir/images/directory/image.gif' when it should be outputting just '/mydir/image.gif'. I hope that makes sense?!

Comment: thanks very much for the quick response - I'll try the updated solution first thing on Monday morning. Really apprechiate your help.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @Tensibai - I've now had a chance to test and I've noticed a slight bug. If the source HTML is '<td width="100%" background="images/shadow-overlay.png" style="background-image:url(images/shadow-overlay.png); background-position:center top; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;" align="center" valign="top">' the output HTML comes out as '<td width="100%" background="/mydir/shadow-overlay.png" );="" background-position:center="" top;="" background-repeat:no-repeat;="" background-size:cover;"="" align="center" valign="top">' Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Lack of code formatting in my comment above deosnt help but it looks like the RegEx is changing the content of the inline styles. The background image URL in the inline style is handled by another RegEx so that's not a problem. Really apprechiate your help with this.

Comment: @MowerDance Maybe you may open a new question, it will be better for the code formatting. (and with the code using the regex itself to see if it's not a race condition)

Comment: @MowerDance never mind, I found why, I let the "path" match greedy and  matching anything. Updating the answer.

Comment: you're a legend. That's fixed the issue and is working perfectly. Thanks very much for your help and quick responses :)